# What format are emails sent in?

Tags: c#, html, email, format

So I was making an email template generator in C# which I thought was going to be pretty straight forward. I have a template in a text file with a few identifiers which will be replaced with the relevant information upon the generation of the template.

The email template has plain, coloured and HTML text in it.

If I copy the email/template contents inside my email client and paste them into a New Email window, they will render fine, just as they were copied.

Now, if I copy them into WordPad, the highlighting/mark-up won't show up.

That's understandable with the HTML, but not with he coloured/bold/styled text. I looked at the message source because I thought of course all this highlighting must be in HTML. However, it was to the contrary.

When you view the email source, it's just plain text with some HTML.

Where is the information about the styled text being stored? Is it RTF format? If so, why doesn't it render in WordPad? How can the email client render it this way even though it appears as if no information about the styling of the text is being transmitted.

Essentially the question is, what format is the email being sent in other than HTML, and how can I extract the text with it's styling information from the email?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The HTML wouldn't happen to have `style` attributes set on it would it? Or the formatting tags `<b>`, `<i>` and so on?

Comment: No, when I view the email source, there are no tags around the styled text. Hence the weirdness. I've viewed the source in about 3 different clients incase you think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that when I viewed the original source of the email it was giving me the plain text and html versions both in one file. The email was very long so I didn't notice the HTML at the bottom of the file.

Thanks anyway.